# Foreach not inserting in fields of MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, insert, foreach

I have a database with authors, books, subjects, publishers etc.

In one of my forms I insert all of the book information and one of the informations are which authors (from the database) wrote the specific book.

I have a many-to-many relationship between the author table and the book table with the table between them named `book_author`. What I do in the book form is insert the authors IDs chosen from a `select multiple` in php into the `book_author` table along with the ISBN of the book so every book_ISBN with author_ID combination will be unique in that table (even though I have not set the combination as a primary key because I have no more information in that table).

The problem is that my foreach statement will insert in the database only once and also if I have many authors chosen (more than 2 usually) it will not insert anything at all.

EDIT: The authors are displayed properly in the `select multiple`

I have checked with `var_dump()` and the array has the correct IDs, example after selecting 2 authors:

`array(2) { [0]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(1) "2" }`

I have even checked if each query is produced correctly, same example:

`string(77) "INSERT INTO book_author (book_ISBN, author_ID) VALUES ('87979695faae','3')"`

`string(77) "INSERT INTO book_author (book_ISBN, author_ID) VALUES ('87979695faae','2')"`

But the problem insists and I have no idea what to do, here is my code:

```
if (!isset($_POST["authors"])){
        header("Location: addBook.php");        
        exit;
}

var_dump($_POST["authors"]);

$authors = $_POST["authors"];

foreach ($authors as $author) 
{
    $sqlAuthor = "INSERT INTO book_author (book_ISBN, author_ID)
        VALUES ('$isbn','$author')";

    var_dump($sqlAuthor);

    mysql_query($sqlAuthor);
}
```

My suspicion would be this `mysql_query($sqlAuthor);` but I'm not sure...

EDIT: I used the `die` function as instructed and this is the error I got

```
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`library`.`book_author`, CONSTRAINT `FK_written1` FOREIGN KEY (`book_ISBN`) REFERENCES `book` (`book_ISBN`))
```

Comment: You are not fetcing any errors. do `mysql_query($sqlAuthor)or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Is `mysql_query()` returning `false` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error tells you what's wrong: Somewhere in setting up your database, you added a foreign key constraint and you are not respecting it when trying to insert your data. Personally I'd suggest just dropping the foreign key, but if it's needed for other reasons then you will need to update your insertion to actually pay attention to constraints.

Comment: to elaborate a bit, you have a table 'book'. With the foreign key restraint in place, you can't insert a data set into 'book_author' if you use an isbn that is not already inserted in 'books'

Comment: yeah I figured that was the problem, but now I changed the way the code compiles but I still get the same error, ho would I get the php code to firstly insert the isbn in the book table then in the book_author table?

Comment: I found it, I did the order of the code wrong and now it is ok. Thank you